# Is there a formal proof of this basic integral property?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

This has really been bothering me because everywhere I have looked the answer has been "A proof has been omitted because the theorem is very intuitive" or "Proofs are very complicated and not worth showing", so I was wondering if there exists a formal proof of the basic integral property:

$$\int_a^bf(x)dx=\int_a^cf(x)dx + \int_c^bf(x)dx$$

This property is absolutely crucial to calculus and it bothers me that I haven't seen any formal proof using the definition of an integral. Does anyone know of a proof?

Edit: This is all assuming that the function is continuous on the intervals [a,b], [b,c] and [a,c]

Comment: Is this for something at the level of Spivak's calculus or Real Analysis?

Comment: I think so. I'm currently enrolled in an AP BC Calculus course.

Comment: It's not true in general.  You must assume that the function is continuous on the intervals $[a, b]$, $[a, c]$, and $[c, b]$.

Comment: This problem is (usually) of no concern in an AP course and is quite above the scope of it... however, I will work on an answer.

Comment: I think it's safe to assume that $f$ is continuous in the three intervals for the purpose of the AP BC Calc. course.

Comment: Jared, my bad, I added the clarification

Comment: Clarinetist, Although I am enrolled in the class I am still very advanced for the course and in general am very good at concepts in math so I don't need it to be aimed at the average AP student

Comment: Do you know about Riemann sums?

Comment: Yes I'm very familiar with Riemann sums and the limit definitions as well

Comment: The proof can be found in Spivak's Calculus, Theorem 4, Chapter 13, p. 267. However, this involves some notions such as $\sup$, $\inf$, etc., which are typically not taught in AP Calculus. I will see if I can find a Riemann-sum proof.

Comment: @Jared Careful. You don't need continuity, but integrability. The good way to put it is, $$\int_a^b f=\int_a^c f+\int_c^b$$ whenever two of the integrals exist.

Comment: I do not own Spivak's Calculus, is there any way someone could get this proof to me?

Comment: And I'd be happy to read up on notions such as sup/inf. The majority of my knowledge comes from me reading it beforehand rather than me being taught it

Comment: Oh joy... Stewart bypasses the proof completely. I will post up an answer (or someone will probably beat me to it).

Comment: Riemann sums will help in its formal proof.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure if I can legally post the proof from Spivak.

Comment: @ASKASK Here is the proof in Spivak: http://qs.lc/ezvrv
It's pretty straight forward from the definition of integration.

Comment: @Fujoyaki Thanks! I really wish I had this book. Looks like I have some reading to do on formal definitions of the integral

Comment: @ASKASK If you're serious about rigour, start here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral
As for the book, you can probably find one in your university's library, or you could buy it on Amazon as it's not expensive.

Comment: Spivak defines integrals using upper and lower sums, which is not quite the same as the Riemann sum method in Stewart. The problem is, with Stewart's notation the proof of this fact is very messy. Since the length of the intervals $[a.c]$ and $[c,b]$ may not be commensurable, there's no clean way to divide each into $M$ and $N$ even pieces of all equal length. One has to then do some ugly approximation argument that would basically reinvents the upper and lower sums notion. This is one of those cases where a picture is really worth a thousand words.

Answer (score 2):

At an elementary level, it is better to consider *continuous* functions and define the integral as a limit of *sequences* of *left* (or *right*) Riemann sums corresponding to *regular* partitions.

Let $f$ be a function continuous on $[a,b]$.

A **partition** of $[a,b]\,$ is a set of points $P=\{x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ with $$a=x_0<x_1<\dots<x_n=b$$ The **norm** of $P$ is the number $$\|P\|=\max_{1\le i\le n}\,(x_i-x_{i-1})$$ If the points are equidistant, $P$ is the **n-regular** partition and is denoted by $P_n\,$, so $$\|P_n\|=\frac {b-a}n$$ The number $$L(f,P)=\sum_{i=1}^n f(x_{i-1})(x_i-x_{i-1})$$ is said the **left sum corresponding to $P$**.
(here $L$ is for Left not for Low)

Now the **comparison of two left sums**.

*Comparison theorem*: any two left sums differ arbitrarily little from each other if the norms of the partitions to which they correspond are sufficiently small.

Formally:

*For every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that, if $\,\|P\|<\delta\,$ and $\,\|P'\|<\delta$, then $$|L(f,P)-L(f,P')|<\varepsilon$$*
($P'=\{x'_0,x'_1,\dots,x'_m\}$)

The proof is based on the (uniform) continuity of $f$.

In fact, if $$K_{ij}=[x_{i-1},x_i]\cap[x'_{j-1},x'_j]$$ then $$L(f,P)-L(f,P')=\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m \,[f(x_{i-1})-f(x'_{j-1})]\,m(K_{ij})$$ where $m(K_{ij})$ is the length of the interval $K_{ij}$.
(really $K_{ij}$ can degenerate in one point or be the empty set)

Now the definition of **definite integral**.

The comparison theorem assures that the sequence $$S_n=L(f,P_n)$$is Cauchy so it has a limit denoted by $$\int_a^b f$$ In fact it is enough to choose $N$ such that $$\frac {b-a}N<\delta$$ to have $$|L(f,P_m)-L(,f,P_n)|<\varepsilon$$ for every $m,n \ge N$.

Finally your question.

If $a<c<b$, one also has $$S'_n=L(f,P'_n) \to \int_a^c f$$ and $$S''_n=L(f,P''_n) \to \int_c^b f$$ where $P'_n$ and $P''_n$ are the n-regular partitions of $[a,c]$ and $[c,b]$ respectively.

Note that $S'_n+S''_n$ is the left sum corresponding to $P'_n \cup P''_n$, a partition of $[a,b]$ that is not regular unless $c$ is the midpoint of $[a,b]\;$ (*so it is important that the comparison theorem is valid for any partition*).

Then one gets $$|S_n- S'_n-S''_n|<\varepsilon$$ for every $n\ge N$.

In fact $\,\|P'_n \cup P''_n\|<\|P_n\|<\delta\,$ for every $n\ge N$.

So one has $$|S_n- S'_n-S''_n| \to \left|\int_a^b f-\int_a^c f-\int_c^b f \right|\le \varepsilon$$ The arbitrariness of $\varepsilon$ gives the result.